# How do I pass an anonymous string literal to a function?

Tags: c, string, character-arrays

Since a string literal can be initialized like

```
char myString [] = "somestring";
```

it seems logical to be able to use a function like

```
int stringLength ( char * str )
{
   char * c2 = str;
   while (*c2++);
   return (c2-str);
}
```

and call it like

```
printf("%d",stringLength("somestring"));
```

However, I get an error when I do that.

Is there some way I can "cast" `"something"` into something proper to input into the function, or do I always have use an extra line like

```
char str [] = "somestring";
printf("%d",stringLength(str));
```

or is there something else I should be doing altogether?

Comment: And, by the way, you have a mistake in `stringLength`. It'd return the string length **including** the 0-terminator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
char myString [] = "somestring";
```

creates an array of characters that are modifiable.

When you use

```
printf("%d",stringLength("somestring"));
```

it is analogous to:

```
char const* temp = "somestring";
printf("%d",stringLength(temp));
```

That's why the compiler does not like it.

You can change the function to use a `char const*` as argument to be able to use that.

```
int stringLength ( char const* str )
{
   char const* c2 = str;
   while (*c2++);
   return (c2-str);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You know that your function "stringLength" will never mutate/change the contents of the string right so make that function so

```
int somefunc(const char* ptr)
{
    const char* base=ptr;
    while(*(ptr++));
    return (ptr-base);
}

int main()
{
    printf("%d",somefunc("HELLO"));
    return 0;
}
```